# Can someone check my schematic and code? My Led is not turning on

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, interrupt, code-review

Led1 is on the left Led2 is on the right The code is making LED1 blink every second but it should also turn on Led2 so that whenever I press the push button it should turn off Led2. But Led2 isn't turning on when I run the code but Led1 is blinking
[image: My schematic]

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#define F_CPU 16000000
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
void setup();
void initInterrupt0();
// ---------Main Program -------------------------------------------
int main()
{
setup();
initInterrupt0();
// ------ Event loop: Just flashing LED-----------------------------
while (1)
{
PORTB ^= 0b00000010; // flash PB1 at 1 sec interval
_delay_ms(1000);
}
}
// -------- Initialization ------------------------------------------
void setup( )
{
DDRB = 0b00000011; // LED PB0, PB1 active
DDRD = 0b00000000; // all inputs
PORTD = 0b00000100; // enable pullup on PD2
}
// ---------- Initializing Interrupt 0 ------------------------------
void initInterrupt0( )
{
SREG |= 0b10000000; // set global interrupt enable bit
EIMSK |= 0b00000001;// enable INT0
EICRA |= 0b00000000; // trigger when button is low
}
// Interrupt Service Routine: Runs every time there is a change on button
ISR (INT0_vect) // INT0 interrupt function
{
int PButton = PIND; // read portd
if (PButton & 0b00000100) // is button PD2 pressed
{
PORTB |= 0b00000001; // turn PB0 on
}
else
{
PORTB &= 0b11111110; // turn PB0 off
}
}
```

Comment: I reposted it because the other code was only screenshots and not formatted

Comment: There both my accounts I made two accounts by accident.

Comment: edit the first post ... delete this one

Comment: I guess you want your interrupt to fire on any change, not only when going low, or it'll never turn on.
Change your EICRA line to 0b00000001.

I also found it very useful to include some macros for setting and clearing bits, so you don't have to write out all the bytes and `|=` / `&=`s manually

Comment: I second @towe 's comment. Secondly; since the button has a pull-up resistor, the PD2 bit of the PIND register will be `0` when the button **is pressed**, and 1 when not pressed. Your code assumes the reverse. Thirdly; you may have to look into debouncing the button. Lastly; indenting your code makes it more readable, for us and yourself.